# if i used angular but handled routing through backend would it be still a single page application?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes, single-page-application, backend

I read that if i handled routing through server, when a client asks for a page resulting the server to render a new document which will also result to refresh the web page unlike frontend/angular routing.

Answer (score 0):

No. It wouldn't be a single page application. If you route through backend, whenever you change a route, your entire application will be bootstrapped in the browser again losing the essence of angularJS